# Getting information from index in ArrayList depending on what Google Maps OverlayItem is being tapped (Android)

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

I have a `User` class in which I have an `ArrayList` of `Bar` objects. I create a bunch of `OverlayItem` objects for my Google Map using this `ArrayList`, i.e. the `ArrayList` holds latitude, longitude, name, and so on. Now I want to be able to tap an `OverlayItem` and get more information about the specific bar, such as address, owner name, website url, etc. An `OverlayItem` only holds latitude, longitude, title, and text snippet, i.e. obviously not enough for the info I want. So how do I tell the `onTap()` function which `Bar` object the specific `OverlayItem` I'm tapping on corresponds to?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this API but can offer some general advice. One option would be to create a `Map` to allow you to convert an `OverlayItem` reference back to the `Bar` object it was created from. Depending on how `onTap` was supplied it may be possible to access outer variables inside it which could give you this information without a map. Another option may be to subclass `OverlayItem` with your own version which includes the data you need, provided the API allows you to create and pass in your own `OverlayItem`s.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I managed to solve the problem by using the `int index` parameter for `onTap()` to access the correct bar, i.e. by calling `User.myBars.get(index)`, since this `index` apparently corresponds to the order in which the `OverlayItem` objects for the bars are created.